# How to add values identified inside a promise to an array in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to add values to an array. Problem is, I can only get the values inside a promise. I tried assigning the values inside the array but when I try to use the array, the only value left is the last one that was assigned.

The values are taken from the page based on the values in a different array. So for example:

```
var array1 = ['1','2','3'];
var array2 = [];

for (i=1;i<array1.length;i++) {
    element(By.xpath(`//div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[${array1[i]}]`)).getText().then(function(elemText){
        array2[i] = elemText;
    })
}
```

I've also tried returning the value:

```
var array1 = ['1','2','3'];
var array2 = [];

for (i=1;i<array1.length;i++) {
    array2[i] = element(By.xpath(`//div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[${array1[i]}]`)).getText().then(function(elemText){
        return elemText;
    })
}
```

But all I got is an array of promises..which, in my case, I can't work with as well because I pass the values on to another method that handles string values and not promises. I know I can make it handle promises, but is there no other way? Or am I just missing something?

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would map each array element to a promise, like such:

```
var array1 = ['1','2','3'];

var promises = array1.map(function(i) {
    return element(By.xpath(`//div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[${i}]`)).getText();
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
    // result is your new array here
});
```

Comment: Yeah i understand that i could just work with the promises but i was hoping there was actually a way to get the values and not the promises.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you put your iteration variable i in global objects. Use let key word:

```
for (let i=1;i<array1.length;i++)
```

And why do you start from 1? Do you want to skip 1st element of array1? Start with 0 and use let as on example and it'll solve your problem. You run the for loop in stack which executes first. Each iteration of for loop puts a callback in callback queue. When loop is finished you have i=3 in your global object. And all 3 callbacks will work with this exact 3. 'let' works only within curly brackets so it'll close on each callback.

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to start from 0 sorry about that. Anyway i don't understand your answer. I'll try it anyway and i'll inform you if it works.